# Windows 11 doesn't remember Sort By anymore

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-11

My Windows 11 used to remember Sort By option on a per folder basis.
But recently, it stopped working, whenever I quit a folder, and open it again, sorting order goes back to default, that is, by name for most folder, by modified date for Download folder.

This is the Bag registry Explorer used to create:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell\{24CCB8A6-C45A-477D-B940-3382B9225668}]
"Rev"=dword:00000000
"FFlags"=dword:41200011
"Vid"="{65F125E5-7BE1-4810-BA9D-D271C8432CE3}"
"Mode"=dword:00000006
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000002
"IconSize"=dword:00000030
"Sort"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,f4,ee,\
  c8,30,32,a8,e2,41,ab,32,e3,c3,ca,28,fd,29,03,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,30,f1,25,\
  b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,01,00,00,00
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,\
  10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0e,00,00,00,90,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,\
  a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,04,00,00,00,78,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:ffffffff
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{30C8EEF4-A832-41E2-AB32-E3C3CA28FD29}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000002
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
```

Notice the "Sort" key, this is how Windows remember the sorting order of a folder.

This is now

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\10\Shell\{B3690E58-E961-423B-B687-386EBFD83239}]
"Mode"=dword:00000001
"LogicalViewMode"=dword:00000003
"FFlags"=dword:41200001
"IconSize"=dword:00000060
"ColInfo"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,fd,df,df,fd,10,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,\
  1a,10,a5,f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0a,00,00,00,10,01,00,00,b4,74,db,f7,87,42,03,\
  41,af,ba,f1,b1,3d,cd,75,cf,64,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,e0,85,9f,f2,f9,4f,68,10,\
  ab,91,08,00,2b,27,b3,d9,05,00,00,00,58,00,00,00,30,f1,25,b7,ef,47,1a,10,a5,\
  f1,02,60,8c,9e,eb,ac,0c,00,00,00,50,00,00,00
"GroupView"=dword:00000000
"GroupByKey:FMTID"="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
"GroupByKey:PID"=dword:00000000
"GroupByDirection"=dword:00000001
```

The "Sort" key is gone.
Tried everything, can't bring it back. The Folder Option method doesn't work, WinSetView is a nice tool, but doesn't address my problem.

Comment: Works fine on my Windows 11 machines - 2 Production, 1 Insider. Did you damage the Sort by trying to manage it via the Registry?  No need to do that.

Comment: Never messed Registry until the problem occure.
My Windows Update is set to Beta.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is I've been testing some keyboard macro to sort folder.
So maybe sorted too many times in a short time?

Comment: Even Windows 10 has sorting issues on occasion -- as well as remembering the fields to display for each file type (Photo, Doc, etc.) Sometimes I've found the only solution was to delete all folder customization and to start over. Also note that customizing a Library or top-level folder does not always propagate to children; I've had to set file type to sub-folders and then customize. Could be just my PC setup, or not.

Comment: Did that, I deleted all BagMRU and Bag notes, all default notes under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults, still don't work.
By the way, I immediately stop using those macros I mentioned.